# How to change my background everytime a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hello everyone I am creating a math game for kids and I want the user to be able to change the background image of their game when he/she clicks a button
I have a space / jungle / desert theme  I tried this code that i found online but it won't work it works here though http://jsfiddle.net/Eqdfs/27/
how come?

Please keep in mind that I am using jquery mobile in my original program and I have a default background set with this code

```
 <style>
body {
    background-image: url("http://s21.postimg.org/9bj52fal3/sdfsdfdsf.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
    margin-right: 200px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
.ui-page {
    background: transparent;
}
.ui-content{
    background: transparent;
}

</style>
```

then i found this code that claims it can add buttons that will change the background image but I cant get it to work in this simple html file yet alone in my actual game

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="//http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.js></script>
<script src="//http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

<style>
body {
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:top-left;
}

body.class1 {
    background-image:url('http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~lotufo/Courses/ia-636-1995/alberto/proj5/html/pattern_Id.gif');
}

body.class2 {
    background-image:url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Pattern_square_16.png');
}

body.class3 {
    background-image:url('http://www.herbactive.com.br/catalog/view/theme/default/image/pattern/pattern-11.png');
}
</style>

<script>
$("#btn1").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class1');
});

$("#btn2").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class2');
});

$("#btn3").click(function() {
 $('body').removeClass();
 $('body').addClass('class3');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<a id="btn1">Noise BG</a><br/>
    <a id="btn2">RVB BG</a><br/>
    <a id="btn3">dunno BG</a>   

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Java tag removed -- I don't see that this question has anything to do with programming in Java.

Comment: sorry i meant to write javascript

Comment: how to get it to work in a normal html file?

Comment: not working i included <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 and changed to <script>

Comment: sorry you already include jquery ..

Comment: yeah i dont know how to wrap the stuff to make it work in a notepad html file

Comment: it works on the jsfiddle

Comment: get rid of the type attribute on your style tag. it should just be `<style> /* CSS */ </style>`
do that and edit your post to show your cleaned up code (with the change to the script tag you mentioned)

Comment: Ok i did it , i am saying the code works in fiddle but not my html notepad doc because i am missing some special wrapper code... do you know what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the real problem is the `jquery-mobile` and `jquery-UI` are conflicting each other. Also there are few markup problems in your design. Try this code and check if its working

**EDIT** Updated jquery. Now the background is changing with single click.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-repeat: repeat;
      background-position: top-left;
    }
    a#btn1,
    a#btn2,
    a#btn3 {
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: #333;
      padding: 0px 15px;
    }
    body.class1 {
      background-image: url('http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~lotufo/Courses/ia-636-1995/alberto/proj5/html/pattern_Id.gif');
    }
    body.class2 {
      background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Pattern_square_16.png');
    }
    body.class3 {
      background-image: url('http://www.herbactive.com.br/catalog/view/theme/default/image/pattern/pattern-11.png');
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <a id="btn1">Noise BG</a>
  <br/>
  <a id="btn2">RVB BG</a>
  <br/>
  <a id="btn3">dunno BG</a> 

  <script>
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
      $('body').removeAttr('class');
      $('body').attr('class', 'class1');
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function() {
      $('body').removeAttr('class');
      $('body').attr('class', 'class2');
    });

    $("#btn3").click(function() {
      $('body').removeAttr('class');
      $('body').attr('class', 'class3');
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this works but it only changes once if you try multiple time to click it doesnt work

Comment: Yes, I can see that. Will sort it out.

Comment: @artbarzz Updated the script, Used removeAttr in place of removeClass. its works.

Comment: perfect works great now i need to add the httml into my jquery butttons ! will this work for jquery buttons?

Comment: You mean adding button dynamically ? Not clear what you really meant !! Mmm.. It may work. Give a try :)

Comment: adding into a button like this  <div data-role="header" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-left">Jungle BackGround!</a></li>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97694/discussion-between-artbarzz-and-jinu-kurian).

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle code actually worked for me running inside MS Edge.

Comment: how do i tag it correctly for it to work in a normal html text file?

Comment: it works in fiddle but not in my html file because i am not doing something correctly with the tags, which tags do i add? or librarys ty

Answer (score 0):

Just Change this line:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
```

to

```
<script>
```

Additionally, You aren't defining type while including script files, Add this line too in each opening `<script>` tag

```
type="text/javascript"
```